# having a problem calculating the running time

Tags: performance, data-structures

I have problem in calculating the running time of the algorithm using Θ.
this is the algorithm:

```
input:a natural number n
i = 2
while i ≤ n do
i = i^2
end while
```

I would appreciate if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

The loop will exit when i's exponent has reached ceil(lg n), because 2^(ceil lg n) >= n by definition.
Every iteration, the exponent of i doubles, because we are squaring it. So, the loop executes Θ(lg lg n) times, each incurring constant cost, giving a total running time of Θ(lg lg n).

edit: Thanks to Pete Kirkham for pointing out that the cost of the arithmetic is not constant as n becomes arbitrarily large. The asymptotically fastest algorithm for integer multiplication would appear to be the [Harvey Hoeven algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%BCrer%27s_algorithm#Improved_algorithms) with a bound of O(n lg n), which would give a total running time of O(n lg n lg lg n).

Comment: n is described as a natural number rather than a fixed length integer, so squaring it is not constant cost: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations#Arithmetic_functions

Comment: I didnt uderstand, the answer is O(nlogn)? How can I write it with tetha notation?

Comment: If you treat the i = i^2 as constant cost, the answer is Θ(lg lg n), the log of the log of n. If you are using very large numbers, the cost of squaring wouldn't be constant, and the whole thing would be O (n lg n lg lg n), ie would increase by a factor of n lg n.

Comment: How can i write it with tetha notation?

Comment: Θ(lg lg n) is written in theta notation.